# Unrecognized input on Ant design vue

Tags: css, less, vuejs3, less-loader, ant-design-vue

While trying to run the newly created Vue 3 application with Ant design Vue (3.1.0-RC.0) framework, I'm getting `unrecognized input` error. Vue configurations are not at all changed. Trying to run with the default settings only.

Command used to run the application `vue-cli-service serve`

- Node: 16.8.0
- TSC: 4.1.6
- Ant Design Vue: 3.1.0-RC.0

[image]